# SSH Connect Using Parallel Threading C#

Tags: c#, ssh

What is the error Please?
the task never completed

`using Renci.SshNet;`
in `Program.cs`

```
static List<string> tasks = new List<string>();
static List<Server> servers = new List<Server>();
```

and in the `Main`

```
var serverFile = File.ReadAllLines("E:/servers.txt");
foreach (var line in serverFile)
{
    var arrayOfInfo = line.Split('|');
    servers.Add(new Server() { IP = arrayOfInfo[0], Username = arrayOfInfo[1], Password = arrayOfInfo[2], IsBusy = false });
}
if (servers.Count == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("No SSH Selected");

var rangesFile = File.ReadAllLines("E:/ranges.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < rangesFile.Count(); i++)
{
    tasks.Add(string.Format("./svmap.py {0} >> output.txt", rangesFile));
}
if (servers.Count == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("No Ranges Selected");
```

and the code to connect by parallel

```
Parallel.ForEach(tasks, async (task) =>
{
    while (servers.Where(m => m.IsBusy == false).Count() == 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }


    List<Server> notBusy = servers.Where(m => m.IsBusy == false).ToList();
    var selectedServer = notBusy.FirstOrDefault();

    try
    {
        selectedServer.IsBusy = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Order {0} is given", task, selectedServer.IP);
        await RunTask(selectedServer, task);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Completed", task);
        selectedServer.IsBusy = false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
});
```

and we have a static method

```
static public async Task RunTask(Server server, string task)
{
    using (var client = new SshClient(server.IP, server.Username, server.Password))
    {
        client.Connect();
        client.RunCommand(task);
        client.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

in `Server.cs`

```
public string IP { get; set; }
public string Username { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public bool IsBusy { get; set; }
```

but the program never completes it's job, could anyone help me fix the bugs ?
i've tried for 72h ..

the program gives the orders but i don't know what is happening next .

Comment: *(1)* Why did you make your methods `async`? All methods on `SshClient` are called synchronously so there is no need for `async` - it just complicates the program (and compiler probably gives you warning about it). *(2)* Accessing `servers` list in `ForEach` by multiple threads is not thread-safe and can result in using one server for multiple tasks at once (and possibly even worse things). *(3)* Did you use debugger to investigate, where exactly does program hang?

Comment: so what is the proper code ? please edit it.

Comment: I do not know why your your code hangs. I just pointed out some problems in you code, that are suspicious or likely to cause some problems. You should debug your code (or add a lot of logging), which should help you find the reason why you program never finishes.